# Conformal measures on a compact metric space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $F: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function. Let $\phi$ be a homeomorphism on $X$. An $e^{\beta F}$ conformal measure is a Borel probability measure $m$ on $X$ such that

$m(\phi(B))=\int_Be^{\beta F(x)}dm(x)$.

Then we say that $m$ is $e^{\beta F}$ conformal for $\phi$. I want to prove that $m$ is $e^{-\beta F\circ \phi^{-1}}$ conformal for $\phi^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your assumption is that the push-forward measure $m\circ \phi=m\circ (\phi^{-1})^{-1}=\phi^{-1} * m$ coincides with the measure with density $e^{\beta F}\textrm{d}m$.

Our question is now about the push-forward measure under $\phi$. Well, we see that 
$$
m=\phi*(\phi^{-1}*m)=\phi* (e^{\beta F}\textrm{d}m)=e^{\beta F\circ \phi^{-1}}\textrm{d} \phi*m,
$$
by the characterising property of the push-forward measure. Now, since this density is invertible, we get that

$$
\phi*m=e^{-\beta F\circ \phi^{-1}}\textrm{d}m,
$$
which is exactly what you wanted.

Comment: What do u mean by the density of a measure? You mean the Radon Nikodym derivative?

Comment: I could not understand the invertibility of density

Comment: Well, for three measures $\mu$, $\nu$ and $\gamma$, if $\mu=f\textrm{d}\nu+\gamma$, I'd call $f$ the Radon Nikodym derivative of $\mu$ with respect to $\nu$. I'd say that $\mu$ has density with the respect to $\nu$ if $\gamma=0$. But sure, I mean a Radon Nikodym derivative.

Comment: For the invertibility, if $\nu=f\textrm{d}\mu$, then $g\textrm{d}\nu=(fg)\textrm{d}\mu.$ Hence, if $\nu$ has an invertible Radon-Nikodym derivative, then $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\nu$ as well and, in fact, $\mu=f^{-1}\textrm{d}\nu$.

Comment: Thank you so much..